# How to retrieve form data and assign it to a text as a url on MVC 4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

i would like to return below url from a search submit where id will be get from database.
So when a user search something by id it will search my database and display the result on my home view. then i want to transform my ID a clickable url which is this one:

http://myadress.com:8787/Handlers/DataExport.ashx?format=pdf&id=**???**&direction=0

Any idea how to do?

**This is my home view:**

```
<body>
            <p>
                @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
                {
                    <b>SEARCH BY:</b> @Html.RadioButton("searchby", "ID", true) <text>ID</text>
                    @Html.RadioButton("searchby", "NAME") <text>NAME</text>
                    <br /><br />
                    @Html.TextBox("search") <input type="submit" value="SEARCH" />
                }
            </p>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        ID
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        NAME
                    </th>

                    <th>Actions</th>
                </tr>
                @if (Model.Count() == 0)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">NO DATA FOUND.</td>

                    </tr>
                }
                else
                {
                    foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ID)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NAME)
                            </td>

                            <td>
                                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.id })
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                }
```

**this is my controller:**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private mydbEntities db = new mydbEntities();
        //
        // GET: /Home/

        public ActionResult Index(string searchBy, string search)
        {
            if (searchBy == "ID")
            {
                return View(db.mytable.Where(x => x.ID == search).ToList());
            }
            else (searchBy == "NAME")
            {
                return View(db.mytable.Where(x => x.NAME == search).ToList());
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just create an anchor tag and substitute the id in the href attribute

```
<a href="http://myadress.com:8787/Handlers/DataExport.ashx?format=pdf&id=@(item.ID)&direction=0">your link text</a>
```

Comment: Hi Lee. Thanks but this didnt work for me. It doesnt get any data for id.

Comment: My apologies, I think I made a mistake in my example. The part in parentheses should be @(item.ID). I will edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

you have to use jquery for this.  something like

```
$('.btnSearch').on('click', function(){
    $('.lnkSubmit').attr('href', '@Url.Action("Action", "Controller", new { id = "----" })'.replace("----", (returned id here));
});
```

this will replace the url of a link with class lnkSubmit and will include the id that you put in it.  Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Hi Matt, can you please explain more. I couldnt figured it out. What do you mean by ---- ?

Comment: "----" is just a place holder.  it is how you combine razor and javascript.  the url.action will build the link for you and then .replace will replace "----" with whatever id you want to use in the link

Answer (score 1):

In my Blog application, this is how I implemented search functionality for searching posts.

**Partial view for search:**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Blog", FormMethod.Get, new {id = "search-form"}))
{
  <input type="text" name="s" placeholder="Search">
  <button type="submit">Go</button>
}
```

**Search action in controller:**

```
public ActionResult Search(string s)
        {
            var model = _dbPostRepository.GetPostsForSearch(s);
            ViewBag.TotalPosts = _dbPostRepository.TotalSearchPosts(s);
            return View("Posts");
        }
```

**Posts View:**

```
@model FirstBlog.Core.Post

@if (@ViewBag.TotalPosts > 0)
{
    foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        Html.RenderPartial("_PostTemplate", item);
    }
}
else
{
    <p>No posts found!</p>
}
```

_PostTemplate is the view for each post. Hope this would help.